# What level of Permission requires to enable MFA on Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation, multi-factor-authentication

Need to enable MFA on Azure AD to the users accounts which iam creating using powershell through Automation account which will runs on Hybrid Worker, so when the user is created will set the timer for few seconds **Start-Sleep -Seconds ** to perform MFA action, please assist me to understand kind of permissions, modules and connections to Azure Ad to enable MFA using automation account using powershell script on Azure AD for the same, i have found some useful documents but there are portal based policies. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you include few more details like what you tried and where you stuck with errors?

Comment: @Sridevi -  iam looking for  required connections/permissions on Azure Automation Account to enable MFA on Azure Ad using Azure Automation Account Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

> To enable MFA on Azure AD, you need to have roles like **Global Administrator** or Security Administrator or Conditional Access Administrator on your Azure AD tenant.

Make sure to acquire `Azure AD Premium P1` license if you want to use conditional access policies for enabling MFA.

Get yourself assigned with **Contributor** role under subscription where your automation account exists.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my local environment and got results like below:***

I ran the below script by connecting with user having **Global Administrator** role that created new user with MFA enabled like below:

```
Connect-MsolService

$user=New-MsolUser -DisplayName "Demo User" -UserPrincipalName "demouser@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" -Password "xxxxxxxxxxxx1234@"

# Wait for the user account to be created
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

$strongAuth = @()
$strongAuth += New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$strongAuth[0].RelyingParty = "*"
$strongAuth[0].State = "Enabled"

Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "demouser@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $strongAuth
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, new user named **`Demo User`** created successfully like below:

[image]

To **check** whether MFA is enabled or not, I tried to sign in with above newly created user credentials that asked for MFA like below:

[image]

If you want to use same script, make sure to install **`MSOnline`** module before running script like this:

```
 Install-Module -Name MSOnline
 Import-Module -Name MSOnline
 Connect-MsolService
```

If you are performing these operations via service principal, you need to assign **roles** or **permissions** for service principal too.

**Reference:**
[Enable Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa#prerequisites)